# Как реализовать MultiView в проекте WindowsTemplateStudio соблюдая mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня небольшой опыт программирования на  C#. Сейчас изучаю создание приложений WPF с помощью шаблонов WindowsTemplateStudio. Возникла необходимость в создании дополнительных окон.

В [описании к WindowsTemplateStudio написано](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/blob/dev/docs/WPF/projectTypes/menubar.md), как это можно сделать:

> 4. Open in a new window.

> Shows a page in a separate Window. This is done with the help of the MultiView feature. You should use the OpenInNewWindow method in the WindowManagerService class. (Except in Prism where you should use the Prism dialog service.) You should add a dependency injection to this service in the ShellViewModel constructor.

Я использую MVVM Toolkit.

Может ли кто-нибудь показать пример кода, как открывать новые окна через WindowManagerService?

Comment: Если у вас опыта в создание как такового нету, то забудьте про всякие шаблоны, сторонние библиотеки и прочее, пишите самостоятельно свой проект, осваивая каждый его аспект. Ну а так, у вас ведь в цитате выше есть ответ `Prism dialog service`, пишем в любом поисковике и сразу, первой ссылкой попадаем на [документацию](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html) с подробным описанием механизма. Но опять же, чтобы это понять, вам надо понять основы MVVM, что такое IoC, контейнеры, внедрение зависимостей, интерфеймсы и куча другого.

Comment: Я использую не Prism, а MVVM Toolkit. Я понимаю основы MVVM, IoC, контейнеры, внедрение зависимостей, интерфейсы.

Comment: Что именно не получается? Покажите код. Судя по документации, там особо ничего сложного не должно быть, ну при услови, что в знакомы и используете IoC контейнер.

Comment: Я уже разобрался, теперь работает.  Не знаю, почему не работало раньше. Сделал инъекцию WindowManagerService в нужную мне ViewModel и вызываю OpenInNewWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сделал так, все работает:

```
public class FirstPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly IWindowManagerService _windowManagerService;
    private ICommand _navigateToNewWindowCommand;
    public FirstPageViewModel(IWindowManagerService windowManagerService)
    {
        _windowManagerService = windowManagerService;
    }

    public ICommand NavigateToNewWindowCommand => _navigateToNewWindowCommand ?? (_navigateToNewWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(NavigateToNewWindow));

    private void NavigateToNewWindow()
    {
        _windowManagerService.OpenInNewWindow(typeof(SecondPageViewModel).FullName);
    }
}
```